# Remote Connection Graphics Limits

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, remote-connection

I have two computers. One has Windows 7 and the other Windows XP. I'm using the Windows XP computer to connect to the Windows 7 computer through Remote Desktop Connection. The problem is I can't install or run certain programs because they state that my graphics are limited. Is there anyway around this?

I don't care if the graphics are bad, laggy, etc; I just the need programs to install and make sure they open.

Note: The Windows 7 computer has two accounts and I have it set up so that two users can be on the computer at once. One physically and the other remotely.